# Failed at the camaro@3.0.15 install script

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

First what I want to do:

I have a XML file and want to get a specific value from it. The XML file could be

```
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <aValue>
        <subject>This is the value I am looking for</subject>
    </aValue>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

and I want to read the value from "subject". I could take a XML to JavaScript converter but then I would have to start a recursive search for the target attribute.

I was hoping https://www.npmjs.com/package/camaro would do the trick but I am not able to install it.

I get this error

https://pastebin.com/kZaNPgya

and this is my log file

https://pastebin.com/LmZwstFf

I tried to install it on multiple machines but they all fail when it comes to the npm installation.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

As the log say

> Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.

You need to install python on your machine or set the PYTHON env

Comment: thanks but why does it depend on Python? I was hoping when installing npm with NodeJs it would be ready to use

Comment: sometime npm module use python or gcc to build native content or to execute some python code